# dashSpeed is defaulting to moveSpeed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason my dashSpeed is defauling to moveSpeed, I feel it's because moveSpeed is overriding it but im not sure why. This is the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera sceneCamera;


    [Header("Dash Settings")]
    [SerializeField] float dashSpeed = 20f;
    [SerializeField] float dashDuration = 3f;
    [SerializeField] float dashCooldown = 1f;

    [Header("Player Attributes")]
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rb;

    [Header("Weapon")]
    [SerializeField] Weapon weapon;
    bool isDashing;
    
    

    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private Vector2 mousePosition;



   
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //processing Inputs
        ProcessInputs();
        
      

        
    }

    void FixedUpdate()

    {
        Move();
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

    }

    void ProcessInputs()
    {

        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

        float moveX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float moveY= Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        
        {
            weapon.Fire();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }

      

        moveDirection = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized;
        mousePosition = sceneCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

       

    }
    

    void Move()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * moveSpeed,moveDirection.y * moveSpeed);

        Vector2 aimDirection = mousePosition - rb.position;
        float aimAngle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rb.rotation = aimAngle;
    }


    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        isDashing = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection.x * dashSpeed, moveDirection.y * dashSpeed);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashDuration);
        isDashing = false;
    }
}
```

I am quite new to unity game dev with only slight knowledge on C#.

Also Apologies if I am using this site slightly wrong or haven't formatted stuff right but I hope someone has some insight on what could be the issue.

Comment: because move happens and overrides the dash..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BugFinder mentioned in their comment, your "Move()" method inside FixedUpdate overrides the rb.velocity.

Even though you're Dashing for "DashDuration" you're calling "Dash()" only once. So it changes the value of rb.velocity for one frame but gets reverted to the moveSpeed velocity in Move() in the next FixedUpdate().

I think you need to move your Move() method inside the if condition inside FixedUpdate like so:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{        
    if (!isDashing)
    {
        Move();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the problem, clearly I still need to learn a lot of the basics of learning unity but this was a great help thanks alot.